# Exception when trying to forward to different url in Tapestry 3

Tags: exception, tapestry, forwarding

I've this tapestry application, I've a html and a backend java class, the html part:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Starter Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span jwcid="@Insert" value="ognl: errorMessage" />
    <form jwcid="@Form" method="POST" listener="ognl:listeners.filterContracts">
        <table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label jwcid='@vitech:Label' element="span" labelOverride="Choose Criteria"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select jwcid="criteriaSelect@Select">
                        <foreach jwcid="@Foreach" source="ognl: criterias" value="ognl:currentCriteria" index="ognl:currentCriteriaIndex">
                            <option jwcid="@Option" selected="ognl:selection[currentCriteriaIndex]" label="ognl:currentCriteria"/>
                        </foreach>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label jwcid='@vitech:Label' element="span" labelOverride="Criteria Value"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input jwcid="@TextField" value='ognl: criteriaValue' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label jwcid='@vitech:Label' element="span" labelOverride="Username"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input jwcid="@TextField" value='ognl: username' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" jwcid="getcontract@Submit" label="ognl: 'Get Contracts'" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

the event listener filterContracts in the java class:

```
public void filterContracts(IRequestCycle cycle) {
    if(cycle.isRewinding()) {
        try {
            errorMessage = "";
            String selectedCriteriaString = cycle.getRequestContext().getRequest().getParameter("criteriaSelect");
            MetlinkVisit metlinkVisit = (MetlinkVisit)getEmployerVisit();
            int selectedCriteria = Integer.parseInt(selectedCriteriaString);
            List<MemberContract> allMemberContractsWithEmployer = loadEmployerBySecurityUser(username);
            if(allMemberContractsWithEmployer != null && allMemberContractsWithEmployer.size() > 0) {
                FilterMembersContractsByCriteria filter;
                List<MemberContract> filteredMembersContractsWithEmployer;
                switch(selectedCriteria) {
                    case 0:
                        filter = new FilterMembersContractsBySSN();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        filter = new FilterMembersContractsByLastName();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        filter = new FilterMembersContractsByGAB();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        filter = new FilterMembersContractsByCertificate();
                        break;
                    default:
                        filter = new FilterMembersContractsBySSN();
                        break;
                }
                filteredMembersContractsWithEmployer = filter.filterAllMembersContractsWithEmployerUsingCriteria(allMemberContractsWithEmployer, criteriaValue);
                if(filteredMembersContractsWithEmployer != null && filteredMembersContractsWithEmployer.size() > 0) {
                    metlinkVisit.setFilteredContracts(filteredMembersContractsWithEmployer);
                    HttpServletRequest request = cycle.getRequestContext().getRequest();
                    HttpServletResponse response = cycle.getRequestContext().getResponse();
                    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
                    String url = uri + "?un=" + username + "&service=external/Metlink:SummaryPage";
                    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    errorMessage = "Criteria doesn't match any record, try different criteria";
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this exception when I forward to Metlink Summary page, and this page is loading fine:

```
Exceptions:
```

java.io.IOException: Closed
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:140)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:86)
org.apache.tapestry.request.ResponseOutputStream.innerWrite(ResponseOutputStream.java:246)
org.apache.tapestry.request.ResponseOutputStream.open(ResponseOutputStream.java:186)
org.apache.tapestry.request.ResponseOutputStream.forceFlush(ResponseOutputStream.java:144)
org.apache.tapestry.engine.AbstractEngine.service(AbstractEngine.java:928)
org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doService(ApplicationServlet.java:197)
com.vitechinc.core.VitechApplicationServlet.doService(VitechApplicationServlet.java:310)
org.apache.tapestry.ApplicationServlet.doPost(ApplicationServlet.java:326)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:527)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1216)
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
com.vitechinc.v3.core.connectionmanagement.ConnectionSettingsFilter.doFilter(ConnectionSettingsFilter.java:79)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1187)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:421)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:493)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:930)
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:358)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:866)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:594)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1058)
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:764)
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:217)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:424)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:489)
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:436)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I guess that something is wrong in the rewinding cycle

Comment: I'm not sure if you have the option but, Tapestry 5 will rock your world. And if someone at work insists on using Tapestry 3, you have to convince him otherwise.